# Drag and Drop between different tables using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am not able to drag and drop the images from 'table a' to 'table b'. i am using the sortable API for dragging and dropping, the problem is once dropped into 'table a' from 'table b' cannot drag and drop from 'table a' to table b'.
can anyone please help? 
here is my sample code...

```
 $( "tbody.table1" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".table1a",
        items: "> tr td",
        appendTo: table2,
        helper:"clone",            
        start: function(){ $table1b.addClass("dragging") },
        stop: function(){ $table1a.removeClass("dragging") }
    })
    .disableSelection();

$( ".table1a",".table1b" ).droppable({
  accept: ".table1b tr td"  
  },
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Do you have a demo, or even some code to share? Anything you have would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code demonstrating drag and drop between two lists:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".list1, .list2").sortable({
      connectWith: ".sortable"
    });
  });
</script>
 <style>
.sortable { list-style-type: none; list-style-position: inside;margin: 0px 12px 8px 0px; width: 60%; padding: 2px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; min-height: 100px;}
.sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1em; height: 18px; border: 2px dashed #d3d3d3 ;  background-color: #eee }
</style>
<div>
  <div">
    <ul class="list1 sortable">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="list2 sortable">
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
      <li>Item 8</li>
      <li>Item 9</li>
      <li>Item 10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help to sort out your issue.

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VDLn3/1/) to check the code implemented in JsFiddle.